# how to separate html from php with working form validation

Tags: php, html, forms

I am new to php. i am working on a simple contact form for my practise.It worked fine,exactly the way i want but when i tried to separate html from my Form.php file and paste it in process.html and then pressed the submit button,without filling in any of the fields, the form submits without doing the form validation and the empty data is not inserted in the db.

All i want to do is to keep html and php both is separate files and want to submit the form using the form validation i did.Any help please????

Here is my code

Form.html

```
<?php require_once "process.php";?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
<div id="form_container">
    <?php $arrmessage = "" ?>
    <div style="color:#F00"><?php if($arrmessage !=""){ echo $arrmessage; }?        ></div>
        <div id="form_heading">New User Registration</div>
        <form name="form1" id="form1" action="process.php?value=submit"     method="post">
    <div class="row_a">
        <div class="cell cell_left">Student Name</div>
        <div class="cell cell_right">
        <input type="text" id="student_name" name="student_name" value="" placeholder="Student Name">
        </div>
        <div class="clear_box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_b">
        <div class="cell cell_left">Email</div>
        <div class="cell cell_right">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="clear_box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_a">
        <div class="cell cell_left">Contact Number</div>
        <div class="cell cell_right">
        <input type="text" id="contact_number" name="contact_number" value="" placeholder="Contact Number">
        </div>
        <div class="clear_box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_b">
        <div class="cell cell_left">Gender:</div>
        <div class="cell cell_right">Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" / >  
        Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" / >
        </div>
        <div class="clear_box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_a">
        <div class="cell cell_left">Interest:</div>
        <div class="cell cell_right">
        Laptop<input type="checkbox" id="" name="interest[]" value="laptop" >
        I-Pad<input type="checkbox" id="" name="interest[]" value="ipad" >
        Mobile<input type="checkbox" id="" name="interest[]" value="mobile" >
        </div>
        <div class="clear_box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_b">
        <div class="cell cell_left">Date of Birth</div>
        <div class="cell cell_right">
        <select name="day">
            <option value="">Day</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>-
        <select name="month">
            <option value="">Month</option>
            <option>January</option>
            <option>February</option>
            <option>March</option>
        </select>-
        <select name="year">
            <option value="">Year</option>
            <option>2001</option>
            <option>2002</option>
            <option>2003</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_a">
        <div class="cell cell_left">Street Adress</div>
        <div class="cell cell_right">
        <textarea id="street_adress" name="street_adress" placeholder="Street Adress"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_b">
        <div class="cell cell_left">City</div>
        <div class="cell cell_right">
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="" placeholder="City" >
        </div>
        <div class="clear_box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_a">
        <div class="cell cell_left">State</div>
        <div class="cell cell_right">
        <input type="text" id="state" name="state" value="" placeholder="State" >
        </div>
        <div class="clear_box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_b">
        <div class="cell cell_left">Country</div>
        <div class="cell cell_right">
        <select name="country">
             <?php  foreach($countries as $list) echo "<option>". $list ."<br/>" . "</option>"; ?>          
            </select>            
                </div>
                <div class="clear_box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row_a">
            <div class="cell cell_right">
            <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="clear_box"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    <br/><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

process.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require_once("database.php");
            if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
                            header("Location:login.php");
                            exit;
                        }
                        if(isset($_REQUEST['value'])){
                        //exit;
                    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
                {   

                    if(empty($_POST['student_name'] )){
                        $arrmessage = "Please Enter Student Name";
                    }elseif(empty($_POST['email'] )){
                        $arrmessage = "Please Enter Email";
                    }elseif(empty($_POST['contact_number'] )){
                        $arrmessage = "Please Enter Contact Number";
                    }elseif(empty($_POST['gender'] )){
                        $arrmessage = "Please Select Gender";
                    }elseif(empty($_POST['interest'] )){
                        $arrmessage = "Please Select interest";
                    }elseif(empty($_POST['day'])){
                        $arrmessage = "Please Enter Day";                   
                    }elseif(empty($_POST['month'])){
                        $arrmessage = "Please Enter Month";
                    }elseif(empty($_POST['year'])){
                        $arrmessage = "Please Enter Year";
                    }elseif(empty($_POST['street_adress'] )){
                        $arrmessage = "Please Enter street_adress";
                    }elseif(empty($_POST['city'])){
                        $arrmessage = "Please Enter City";
                    }elseif(empty($_POST['state'] )){
                        $arrmessage = "Please Enter State";
                    }elseif(empty($_POST['country'] )){
                        $arrmessage = "Please Enter Country";
                    }else{
                        $arrmessage ="";    
                }

                if($arrmessage =="")
            {       
                $student_name = $_POST['student_name']; 
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $contact_number = $_POST['contact_number'];
                $gender = $_POST['gender'];
                $interest = $_POST['interest'];
                $checked ="";
                foreach($interest as $list){$checked .= $list .",";}
                $DOB = $_POST['day'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['year'];
                $street_adress = $_POST['street_adress'];
                $city = $_POST['city'];
                $state = $_POST['state'];
                $country = $_POST['country'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO form (student_name,email,contact_number,gender,interest,DOB,street_adress,city,state,country)VALUES('{$student_name}','{$email}','{$contact_number}','{$gender}','{$checked}','{$DOB}','{$street_adress}','{$city}','{$state}','{$country}')";
            mysql_query($sql);
            if(mysql_insert_id() != ""){
                    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
                    }
                    header("Location:views.php");
                    exit;
                }
            }
                }
    $countries = array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegowina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Congo, the Democratic Republic of the", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia (Hrvatska)", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "France Metropolitan", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard and Mc Donald Islands", "Holy See (Vatican City State)", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", "Korea, Republic of", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao, People's Democratic Republic", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States of", "Moldova, Republic of", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcairn", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia (Slovak Republic)", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St. Helena", "St. Pierre and Miquelon", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Taiwan, Province of China", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania, United Republic of", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (British)", "Virgin Islands (U.S.)", "Wallis and Futuna Islands", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"); 

    ?>
```

Comment: You cannot execute php in a html file, (Unless you've told your server to parse html files as php, but I doubt this is the case).

Comment: Ok, first of all, you gotta tell us where you read this tutorial that insists in teaching people to use deprecated `mysql_` functions instead of `mysqli_` or `PDO`, I'm gonna have a serious chat with the maintainers.

Comment: Second, `Form.html` is and `html` page and will **only** parse HTML markup. If you want those `php` tags to interpret PHP code, change the file extension to `.php`

Comment: sorry the file name is form.php NOT form.html

Comment: CODE INDENTATION, CODE indentation, code indentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not execute php code in html file.So, make form.html file extension to form.php
and pass a get parameter while you redirecting to form.php from process.php if error occurs.

check that if get parameter available in form.php then render the message.

```
       if($arrmessage =="")
        {       
            $student_name = $_POST['student_name']; 
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $contact_number = $_POST['contact_number'];
            $gender = $_POST['gender'];
            $interest = $_POST['interest'];
            $checked ="";
            foreach($interest as $list){$checked .= $list .",";}
            $DOB = $_POST['day'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['year'];
            $street_adress = $_POST['street_adress'];
            $city = $_POST['city'];
            $state = $_POST['state'];
            $country = $_POST['country'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO form (student_name,email,contact_number,gender,interest,DOB,street_adress,city,state,country)VALUES('{$student_name}','{$email}','{$contact_number}','{$gender}','{$checked}','{$DOB}','{$street_adress}','{$city}','{$state}','{$country}')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        if(mysql_insert_id() != ""){
                echo "Records inserted successfully.";
                }
                header("Location:views.php");
                exit;
         } else {
                 header("Location:form.php?error=1&msg=$arrmessage");
         }
```

At form.php file you need to check that get if $_GET['error'] then display the message you get in $_GET['msg']

Comment: it did this and im getting error msg in querystring.i think $_POST instead of $_GET will work because i used post in form action.